# Why do you need to escape spaces when passing SCP filenames?

Tags: scp

Anyone who's ever SCP'd knows that this probably doesn't work:

```
scp foo.txt 'me@remote.net:foo bar.txt'
```

For me on this one, I get: "ambiguous target".

The man page for SCP doesn't explain why you need to escape that space, yet the argument seems to fit the specification for that argument listed in the man page:

```
[[user@]host1:]file1
```

Seems to match, to me. So, **why is it required to do this:**

```
scp foo.txt 'me@remote.net:foo\ bar.txt'
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the first case, you are specifying two files as copy target, both residing on `remote.net`. This is clearly ambiguous, as the program cannot determine where to copy the file.

Consider the following, working example specifying two source files and one destination (directory) using the same format:

```
scp 'me@example.org:file1 file2' .
```

This will copy *both* `file1` and `file2` from `example.org` to the local directory.

---

Your local `scp` program connects to the remote host and starts another instance of of `scp` with a parameter determining whether you're transferring files *from* it (`-f`), or *to* it (`-t`). You can see this when you add the argument `-v` for verbose output. The source/destination parameter you enter (`host:file`) is split and the file names part simply appended as additional parameters specifying the files to use.

When using it as *source*:

```
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -f -- file1 file2
```

This works without problem, it transfers multiple source files over the network.

When using it as *sink*:

```
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -t -- file1 file2
```

This fails, as you're intending to write to multiple files. Now the way around this is to escape the file name *again* (once for the local shell, once for the remote call):

```
$ scp foo 'me@example.org:foo\ bar'
[...]
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -t -- foo\\ bar
```

And FWIW, `scp foo 'me@example.org:"foo bar"'` works just as well.

Comment: When viewing the verbose output it's obvious that this is much more efficient than the otherwise equivalent `scp me@example.org:file1 me@example.org:file2 .`

Comment: Seems to me that the SCP man page ought to use "files", if more than one can be specified. There is a curious `...`, and that might indicate more than one file, but I took it as "more stuff in other arguments" and opposed to "more stuff in this argument".